# How do I import a .tar.gz file on Windows/WAMP/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, import, tar, gzip

My web host just sent me a database back up from last week that I'd like to take a look at but it's a .tar.gz

phpmyadmin doesn't recognise the file in my import folder, just .sql files. And Sypex Dumper isn't picking it up either.

I decompressed it in 7-Zip but no dice with .tar either.

I am on Windows 7 and use Wamp too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use 7zip to see what is in the .tar file.

Comment: Oh yeah what a idiot! They have sent me our web folder back up, not a database file. Will keep trying! Thanks.